# Запретить удаление первых двух символов в TextField

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Сейчас использую для ограничения ввода символов:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Не получается через него и ограничить удаление первых двух символов. Пробовал так:

```
if (textField.length == 0)
{
    return = YES;
}
if (textField.tag == 100)
{
    int countLatter = [@"2" intValue];    
    if(textField.text.length <= countLatter)
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Но оно запрещает ввод символов если введено 2 меньше 2х символов, и это понятно. Подскажите, как получить нужный мне результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас нет возможности проверить, но удаление скорее всего можно поймать через передающийся в этот метод параметр на что меняем (`replacementString:(NSString *)string` ), для удаления он наверняка будет либо нулом, либо нулевой длины (что конкретно это уж сами посмотрите). Понять трогают ли при удалении первые два символа можно из shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html).

Можно перед редактированием в

```
textFieldDidBeginEditing
```

сохранять текущее значение поля, и если после редактирвоания там что-то не так в

```
textFieldDidEndEditing
```

можно присваивать полю нужное значение

Answer (score 0):

Надо одновременно проверять length и string

Вот так:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
if (textField.text.length > (int)2) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    if (![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
    }
}
```